# How do I read double quotes(") or single quotes(') through command line into my perl program?

Tags: perl, shell

I am trying to use use arguments passed as command line arguments into my script, But while doing so the double quotes(") and single quotes(') vanishes.
for example on running the following:

```
#!usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $argument_list = join(" ",@ARGV);

print "$argument\n";
```

Upon running the above code:

```
perl test1.pl name1 "name2 and name3"
```

I am getting the following output:

```
name1 name2 and name3
```

Is there any way to include the double quotes along with the command line arguments so that the final argument is `"name2 and name3"` and not just `name2 and name3` ?

I have tried using '\' to escape double quotes `perl test1.pl name1 \"name2 and name3\"` but it only makes it worse by considering `"name2` as a separate argument `and` as a separate argument and `name3"` as another argument.

Comment: Your code does not compile and run as posted. You claim to use `strict`, yet, you have `print "$argument\n";` with no `$argument` declared anywhere. It is best not to lie to people whose help you are seeking.

Answer (score 3):

The behavior you are seeing is a function of the shell you are using, and does not have anything to do with `perl`. You would see the same results whether you used Python or C or some other language.

It is up to you to understand how the programming environment *you* chose works before starting to program. For example, with this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

print join('|', @ARGV), "\n";
```

in `zsh`:

```
 ./1tt.pl name1 "name2 and name3"
name1|name2 and name3
```

That is, the script gets two arguments. `name1` and `name2 and name3`. The double-quoted string is passed as a single argument. On the other hand, see:

```
$ ./1tt.pl name1 "name2 and name3"
name1|name2 and name3
$ ./1tt.pl name1 "\"name2 and name3\""
name1|"name2 and name3"
$ ./1tt.pl name1 '"name2 and name3"'
name1|"name2 and name3"
$ ./1tt.pl name1 "'name2 and name3'"
name1|'name2 and name3'
```

On the other hand, on Windows 10, in a `cmd.exe` window:

```
C:\> perl t.pl name1 "name2 and name3"
name1|name2 and name3
C:\> perl t.pl name1 """name2 and name3"""
name1|"name2 and name3"
C:\> perl t.pl name1 "\"name2 and name3\""
name1|"name2 and name3"
C:\> perl t.pl name1 '"name2 and name3"'
name1|'name2 and name3'
```

etc

Answer (score 1):

There's two problems here - the first is that the shell is unwrapping your quotes *first* before passing them to perl. So you need to escape them.

The second is - `@ARGV` splits on whitespace.

So to do what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

use Text::ParseWords qw ( quotewords ) ;

my $input =  "name1 \"name2 and name3\"";
my @words = quotewords ( " ", 0, $input );

print Dumper \@words;
```

Or reading `@ARGV`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
use Text::ParseWords qw ( quotewords ) ;

my @words = quotewords ( " ", 0, join (" ", @ARGV) );

print Dumper \@words;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet is not working as the $argument is undefined. However I tried this updated and it works as you desired. See the output below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
#use Data::Dumper;

my $argument_list = join(" ",@ARGV);

print "$argument_list\n";
```

Here's the output:

```
$ perl test1.pl name1 \"name2 and name3\"
name1 "name2 and name3"
$ perl test1.pl name1 name2 and name3
name1 name2 and name3
```

Comment: Thanks @SinanÜnür. Corrected it. I didn't execute it on the command line, instead used it as an argument to perl interpreter hence it worked with that mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code a bit to illustrate the points:

```
for ($c=0; $c<=$#ARGV; $c++) {print "ARGV[$c] = $ARGV[$c]\n";}
my $argument_list = join(" ",@ARGV);
print "$argument\n"; # you meant argument_list
print "ArgLst = $argument_list\n";

$ perl test.pl 1  two       "3 four" " 5 six"
ARGV[0] = 1
ARGV[1] = two
ARGV[2] = 3 four
ARGV[3] =  5 six

ArgLst = 1 two 3 four  5 six
```

NOTE:

1. Without the quote, arguments are separated by space(s)
2. The quote forces the interpreter to treat characters (including spaces) inside the quote as one string
3. "join" command concatenates the arguments together. Looking at the ArgLst alone, you wont be able to tell which is the 2nd argument.

I dont know 100% about your question. I hope the code indirectly answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I think I know what you're after now.

```
$ perl test1.pl name1 "\"n2 and n3\"" 
$ name1 "n2 and n3"
```

1st & last double-quotes are for the string the \" is a char and not part of the delimiter. More elegantly, you can have it as follows:

```
$ perl test1.pl name1 '"n2 and n3"'
$ name1 "n2 and n3"
```